# Upgrading Xamarin Forms to .Net MAUI async Task

Tags: maui

In my ContentPage I have a method `CollectDataAsync` it calls some async Task. This is working fine in my Xamarin Forms but it never returns in .Net MAUI . Is this the correct way to call a `async Task` in .Net MAUI?

```
  var CollectionTask = CollectDataAsync();


  public async Task CollectDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // UI Thread
            //OnboardingUI.IsVisible = false;
            //LandingPageBusyIndicatorUI.IsVisible = true;
            //LandingPageBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

            await GetContentData("Home", (int)PageContentEnum.Home);
        }
    }

public async Task GetContentData(string key, int pageid)
{
    try
    {
        if (Connection.IsInternetEnabled())
        {
            ContentService cs = new ContentService();


            var getPageContent = await cs.GetPageContentItemByIdAsync(pageid);

            if (getPageContent.Status == Status.Ok)
            {
                var dbExistingPageContent = await App.LocalDB.GetPageContentByIdAsync(pageid);
                if (dbExistingPageContent != null && getPageContent.Data != null && dbExistingPageContent.LastUpdated < getPageContent.Data.LastUpdated)
                //if (dbExistingPageContent.LastUpdated == null)
                {
                    dbExistingPageContent.Text = getPageContent.Data.Text;
                    dbExistingPageContent.LastUpdated = getPageContent.Data.LastUpdated;
                    await App.LocalDB.UpdatePageContentAsync(dbExistingPageContent);
                }
                else if (dbExistingPageContent == null)
                {
                    ContentDto Content = new ContentDto();
                    Content.PageId = getPageContent.Data.ItemDictionaryId;
                    Content.Text = getPageContent.Data.Text;
                    Content.LastUpdated = getPageContent.Data.LastUpdated;
                    await App.LocalDB.InsertPageContentAsync(Content);
                }
            }

        }
        var content = await App.LocalDB.GetPageContentByIdAsync(pageid);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
        //Crashes.TrackError(e);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `GetContentData` does? Does it any further async calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the `Task.Run` method to start the task:`GetContentData` on a separate thread. This will allow the task to run asynchronously and return control to the calling method, so that it can continue executing:

```
public async Task CollectDataAsync()
{

       Task.Run(async () =>
       {
              await GetContentData();
       });
      
}
```

Comment: This is only valid if the called method is CPU bound (in which case making it `async` would be a mistake in the first place). Otherwise this answer leads to worse performance and increased resource usage for no good reason.

Comment: what do you mean CPU bound? I have attached the GetContentData method.